# insert special character with editor and set font family dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, aloha-editor

Is there a way of using jquery to listen to an event live and check that a special character has been inserted on the page with Aloha editor and jquery will set this special character to an inline style of

```
font-family: FontAwesome
```

For instance, I am using Aloha editor and when I insert a special character (which is a "tick"), the editor insert the special character and uses the body font family but this special character needs to be set to font-family: FontAwesome which converts the special character to a tick like this one: `&#xf00c;`
So at present when I insert the special character it looks like [] instead of the "tick".

I don't know if this will add any additional information but the character picker plugin settings that I use for the configuration in Aloha Editor:

```
characterpicker: {
        // this is the global setting
        config: ['&#xf00c;'],
        editables: {
            // this will disable the characterpicker for the header
          //  '#header': '',
            // allow more characters for editables with class 'article'
           // '.aloha-editable': ['&#38','&#34','&#162','&#8364','&#163','&#165','&#xf00c;']
        }
},
```

Thanks :)